# Best way to deal with deadlock in SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I'm getting frequent deadlocks on SqlServer 2008. Currently, I have the following code in my data access layer to deal with it. It basically catches the deadlock and tries to resubmit the command with a new connection. No transactions. But it doesn't seem to work - users still get exceptions and my log shows that most of those exceptions were deadlocks. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
private static SqlDataReader ExecDataReader(SqlCommand comm, CommandBehavior behavior)
    {
        try { return comm.ExecuteReader(behavior); }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            if(ex.Number == 1205 && comm != null)
            {
                // Deadlock. Can't resubmit with the same connection,
                // have to recreate it.
                SqlParameterCollection pars = comm.Parameters;
                string str = comm.Connection.ConnectionString;
                string sproc = comm.CommandText;
                int t = comm.CommandTimeout;
                try
                {
                    comm.Cancel();
                    if(comm.Connection != null &&
                            comm.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                        comm.Connection.Close();
                }
                catch { }
                // Trying to execute it after a random number of seconds
                // in order not to get a deadlock again by executing both
                // deadlocked commands at the same time. The GetRamdom
                // method works as expected, returns totally random number
                // in expected range
                Thread.Sleep(GetRandom());
                SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(str);
                conn2.Open();
                SqlCommand comm2 = conn2.CreateCommand();
                comm2.CommandText = sproc;
                comm2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm2.CommandTimeout = t;
                CopyParameters(pars, comm2);
                return ExecDataReader(comm2, behavior);
            }
            else throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to look at what is causing the deadlock to solve your issue. Usually it's a case of two connections trying to do the same things, but in a different order. For instance if both processes A and B place exclusive locks, and connection 1 does A then B, but connection 2 does B then A, you can get into the situation where each connection is waiting for the other to yield its lock. In my experience, a common cause is bulk deletes, as they can easily cause lock escalations. Trying to keep your transactions as small as possible can also help.

Comment: Occasional deadlocks are unavoidable and OK.  Frequent and/or regular deadlocks are not.  They are generally caused by some combination of your SQL queries, data design and DB configurations.  So you would need to show us those.  The C# code you have posted to the SQL-tagged question looks fine.

Comment: Another approach to avoiding deadlocks is, if you know what bits of code frequently deadlock against each other, to place a 'process' lock around these pieces of code, using `sp_getapplock`. This enforces a 'critical path' so that only one process can attempt to lock a notional resource at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not common for a read to cause a deadlock but it can happen
It will only happen if it conflicts with an update transaction

Look at all the read and updates

I know I am going to get lambasted for this but try the reader command with (no lock)
You can get dirty reads but then your reads will not cause nor be the victim of a deadlock
If that works you can try rowlock

Maybe post the locks and update command(s)

What you want is consistent order of updates
Try and break up the updates
If you really need to update a lot of rows some times you are better off taking a tablock

Another thing to look at is for the Readers you have get in and get out
Don't do processing in the Reader.Read and hold the connection open
Close the reader and connection as soon as you are done

Comment: I completely forgot about the possibility not to lock the reader. Thank you for reminding me about that!

Answer (score 1):

Your C# looks fine. But sometimes deadlocks are just unavoidable for various reasons. You need to detect the statement/sproc where deadlocks still happen and use the sp_getapplock to lock that code on the server level.

Comment: as this is an answer it is of low quality. You could improve by showing examples in your code.

Comment: Thanks. But the use of sp_getapplock can be coded in a dozen of ways. The question was about ways to combat deadlocks and not about details on how to code any particular way. By looking at his code sample I can tell that the author seem to be a seasoned programmer who is not looking for code samples.